# method range of object _worksheet failed Error

Tags: excel, vba

I always get this error while i compile this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As String
Dim x As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Budget")
x = range("A20").Value

For i = 2 To 20
    If Cells(i, 1) = x Then
        rng = ws.range(ws.Cells(i, 17)).Value
    End If
Next I
MsgBox rng

Worksheets("Shortage").Activate
Worksheets("Shortage").range(rng).Activate

End Sub
```

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: The fact that it says `range` instead of `Range` makes me think that you might have a variable or function or module or worksheet or something with a name of `range` which is therefore confusing things.

Comment: you are overcomplicating things, you can replace your `rng = ws.range(ws.Cells(i, 17)).Value` with `rng = ws.Cells(i, 17)` since you are looking at a single cell

Comment: @ShaiRado - `rng = ws.Cells(i, 17)` and `rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 17)).Value` do two completely different things.  The first just returns the value in Cells(i, 17), the second is an indirect lookup using the value in Cells(i, 17) to specify the cell whose value is to be returned.

Comment: @YowE3K thanks, didn't know about using `Indirect` in this method

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks for your help, I edited the code then i get this error : "Application definded or object defined error" any help is appreciated